# How to show a message in android when internet access not available in webview and hide the url?

Tags: android, webview

How to show a message in an android app when internet access not available in webview and hide the URL?   I don't want to display the URL and progressbar if the internet connection is not available.

This is my code. Please provide me the correct code. I am a beginner to android.

```
public class WebViewClientDemoActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    WebView web;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.loadUrl("http://www.vijaytutorials.com/mo");
    }

    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    // To handle "Back" key press event for WebView to go back to previous screen.
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
            web.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you encountering any exceptions or what does not work?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I solved it just now. What I did is if the device is offline, then the custom html shows up with a message showing why it could not connect to internet.
Copy paste this in your webview Activity.

> final Activity activity = this;

```
mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                    String description, String failingUrl) {
                 String summary =
                 "<html><body>Could not connect to the server.</body></html>";
                 mainWebView.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);

                Toast.makeText(activity, "" + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        });

        webview.loadUrl("http://www.tipfortechs.com/");
```

Then use the following code to check if the device is connected to internet or not, add the following code in the same activity.

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager
                .getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null;
    }
```

At last do not forget to use permission in your Manifest.

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Hope it helps.
Your code Edited:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

/*
 * Demo of creating an application to open any URL inside the application and clicking on any link from that URl 
should not open Native browser but  that URL should open in the same screen.

- Load WebView with progress bar
 */
public class WebViewClientDemoActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    WebView web;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    final Activity activity = this;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);



        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                    String description, String failingUrl) {
                 String summary =
                 "<html><body>Could not connect to the server.</body></html>";
                 web.loadData(summary, "text/html", null);

                Toast.makeText(activity, "" + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        });


        web.loadUrl("http://www.vijaytutorials.com/mo");
    }

    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    // To handle "Back" key press event for WebView to go back to previous screen.
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
            web.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager
                .getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the error handler for WebView and either display a Toast or show an image that you created that tells the user there was a network error:

```
@Override
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String url)
{
    view.loadUrl("file:///[your error image or page goes here]");
}
```

Comment: Actually i am a beginner to android and i had downloaded the sample project and i am editing that file. I request you to please add that code in my above code and post it back to me. Is it possible if i send you my project to your mail id and you do it for me...?

Answer (score 0):

You can check wireless connection state by using the following code.

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

if (mWifi.isConnected()) {
// hide url or whatever you want to do
}
```

DO NOT forget to add permission in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
```

Cheers,

Comment: Actually i am a beginner to android and i had downloaded the sample project and i am editing that file. I request you to please add that code in my above code and post it back to me. Is it possible if i send you my project to your mail id and you do it for me...?

Comment: Sure you can send me the project and I will make it work...but It mai take a few days until I have time...now I have a deadline and I dont have time.

Comment: But sir could you please give me your email id so that i can send my project to you...